# Creating a floating (streaming) water layer on a stationary layers of water

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

Kelp are efficient for reusable energy and bone meal production and the
max height of a kelp can be 26 blocks.

So **my design aim**:

- Have 26 (height) layers of stationary water for kelp to grow
- Make the second layer from bottom slabbed to be able to break all kelp
  from their second breakpoint whenever you wish
- Let the design makes broken kelp reach to the surface eventually by
  buoyancy of water
- 27th layer must be a floating, streaming water layer (width of 8) to
  transport the kelp to the edge in the flowing direction

Please see the **sketch attached** (sorry it's layout is improper).

*L* : Layer

- *Width*: I said 8 since 1 layer of water can transport items up to 8
  blocks. Your solution proposal of course may change this
- *Height*: I said 27 since max height of a kelp can be 26 blocks + 1
  layer of floating water become 27 layers. Your solution proposal of
  course may change this (if >1 layers needed after 26th layer)
- *Len(gth)*: I said 5 since one may break farest kelp if slabbed layer is
  only at 1 side. If slabbed layers are at both sides then length can
  be 2 * 5 = 10

**I tried**:

- Filled 25 layers with stationary water
- Filled 26th layer with a solid block
- Made a flowing (streaming) water on 27th layer
- Broke the solid blocks on 26th layer
- Dived into water and tried to fill 26th layer with water again

I **encountered several issues** at my different trials:

- Kelps did not go up (buoyancy of water failed)
- Kelps stuck at edge (hoppers couldn't pull them or they didn't
  fall)

May you please help me?

1. Is this achievable?
2. How to achieve this design idea?

[image: minecraft bedrock edition - creating a floating (streaming) water layer on a stationary layers of water]

Comment: Try showing us a screenshot how you did it before it failed. Perhaps a sketch encased in glass/barriers will do.

Comment: Thanks. I will asap. Please notice the part I wrote in my question under **I tried** if you didn't.

Comment: I'm wondering what has happened, can you post it now? The image of the draft is slanted so it's hard to focus it as a computer user.